How can I delete a column from several CSV files?
I have a list of csv files, and for each csv file I would like to cut the 4th column.
Now in each csv file I could use:
:%normal! 03f,dt,

to cut the 4th column.
However there's still a bit cumbersome as there are more than 100 files.
Is there a way to speed it up?
For example I tried:
:%normal! 03f,dt,|w

to save the modified csv file, but it does not work.
Also, in each csv file after modification, I'll use <C-6> to "go back to previous file", is there a way to automate that also?
I tried to record the actions I did in the list file for each file as a macro; but in the list file seems the macro could not record what I typed in command mode i.e. the :normal! 03f,dt, part.

Chaining the normal command
The normal command parse the entire line.
To circumvent that problem you can use the execute command that accepted to be chained using the | operator.
You could then do:
execute "%normal! 03f,dt," | write

To chain with <C-6> you could do:
execute "%normal! 03f,dt," | write | execute "normal! \<C-6>"

Or:
execute "%normal! 03f,dt," | write | edit #

Using the arglist
But if I have do an action on a list of csv file I would use the argdo command:

Add the csv file to the arglist: :argadd *.csv
Run the command and update the files: argdo execute '%normal! 03f,dt,' | update


I forgot the normal call. I have corrected the solution :-)

I think I would use edit # rather than execute "normal! \<C-6>"

learnt something new :) @D.BenKnoble

To repeat actions across files, you usually want to use :argdo, :bufdo, :cdo, or a few other similar commands for windows or tabs.
For example, you might start Vim like vim my-csvs*, and then
:argdo %normal! 03f,dt,
:wqall

(assuming you have hidden set). Without hidden, you need :argdo execute '%normal! 0f,dt,' | update and you can just :quit.

I would encourage you to add Miller to your CSV toolkit. For example, we then get
:argdo %!mlr --csv --hi cut -f 4

which is far more robust to quoted commas in fields, for example, and likely to be faster. I've used --hi (--headerless-csv-input) to keep the "4th field", but without it you can name the field you're cutting (cut -f my_field).
Also, mlr fits in *nix toolkits, so you could do the whole thing with something like
find . -name 'my*csv' -exec mlr -I cut -f my_field {} +

